# Vim remote editing: why no --remote-send-silent?

Tags: vim

I would like to send commands to a named vim server. If the named server
doesn't exist, it should be created automatically, and the commands run in the
new instance of vim.

My problem is that there isn't a "silent" version of `--remote-send`. I think an
option such as `--remote-send-silent` would do exactly what I want, but it
doesn't exist.

Is there a way to achieve this? Alternatively, is there a way to
query (programmatically) whether a named vim server exists, so I can switch
the behaviour accordingly?

Comment: I guess nobody needed this so far; a patch to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) would probably be well received.

Comment: You can use    --serverlist to see which named servers exist.